# Why is this IF-THEN line working without an END IF?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I've a question about If command.

```
For x = 2 To 8
If ComboBox1.ListCount < 7 Then ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(x, 13).Value
Next x'
```

Why does this work without errors? There is no End if statement. 
I don't know if it matters, but this code is in the UserForm_Activate() procedure.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `End If` if there is only one statement enclosed in the `If` and it is on the same line as the `If` statement.

Answer (score 3):

VBA (and VB6 and VB.Net) do not require an `End If` when the statement following the `Then` keyword is on the same line of code.